# Microcontroller linear potentiometer output

Tags: arduino, zero, calibration

OK, the next question is: If I added a press button to the digital input could I then use this to calibrate the potentiometers to zero?

Whereby when I press the button all values start from zero no matter what possition the pots are in? I was going to do this in Excel after, however it seems possible to attempt it this afternoon. Would you use a switch statement or some sort of if statement?

```
float ZPot = 0;
float YPot = 1;
float XPot = 2;
byte Reset = 10;

void setup()
{
    pinMode(XPot, INPUT);
    pinMode(YPot, INPUT);
    pinMode(ZPot, INPUT);
    pinMode(Reset, INPUT);

    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
    ZPot = analogRead(0)/ 1023.0 * 105.0;
    YPot = analogRead(1)/ 1023.0 * 105.0;
    XPot = analogRead(2)/ 1023.0 * 105.0;
    Reset = digitalRead(10);

    Serial.print("X Pot [mm] = ");
    Serial.print(XPot    );
    delay(500);

    Serial.print("   Y Pot [mm] = ");
    Serial.print(YPot    );
    delay(500);

    Serial.print("   Z Pot [mm] = ");
    Serial.println (ZPot  );
    delay(500);
}
```

Comment: Please create another question do not edit old ones we'll end up with most comment making no sense...

Comment: Alex, I have updated my solution to include calibration. Please pay attention that I have changed Reset to int, not byte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already almost there. You need to change only two things:

```
float ZPot = 0;           
float YPot = 1;          
float XPot = 2;
int Reset = 10;
float ZCalibration = 0;
float YCalibration = 0;
float XCalibration = 0;
```

and

```
Reset = digitalRead(10);
ZPot = (analogRead(0) / 1023.0 * 105.0) - ZCalibration;
YPot = (analogRead(1) / 1023.0 * 105.0) - YCalibration;
XPot = (analogRead(2) / 1023.0 * 105.0) - XCalibration;

if (Reset == HIGH) {
    ZCalibration = ZPot;
    YCalibration = YPot;
    XCalibration = XPot;
}
```

Comment: Whereby the first change won't make any difference in normal operation, but it's good style to initialize to 0 or -1 so you know when something went wrong with analogRead. If someone's life depends on this program, please leave it to a professional as there are many checks that need to be done.

Comment: Thank you, I tried the second one first as it was fastest to try. Adding / 1023.0 * 105.0;  to the end of the analog read works. However Changing the float values does not work. The floats must be set to the analog inputs 1,2&3.   I will try the First solution later this evening.

Comment: I mean the assignments right at the beginning of the code you posted - there you just set the variables to their initial values (before the first read). This shouldn't make any difference for analogRead, as it will replace these values anyways. Thanks for accepting the answer :)

Comment: Thank you for your help, and don't worry no ones life is in danger from this code, I will use the potentiometers on a low level race car to try and record if the front suspension is moving in comparison to the steering wheel, I have then used an Iphone with 2 data logging applications to record acceleration through 3 axis, as well as: speed, distance traveled and possition to try and get a better understanding of how the car is behaving during a corner.

Comment: Wow, this sounds amazing! Have fun :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the function

```
float convertToMM(float reading)
{
  return reading/1023.0*105.0;
}
```

And then when you do the reading do instead

```
ZPot = convertToMM(analogRead(0));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the answers, you could also use the [map()](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Map) function:

```
ZPot = map(analogRead(0),0,1023.0,0,105);
YPot = map(analogRead(1),0,1023.0,0,105);
XPot = map(analogRead(2),0,1023.0,0,105);
```

It might be faster to do the manual operation, rather than calling map(), but if you're program isn't very complex, this should be fine. Otherwise, you might consider writing the expression `(analogRead(0) / 1023.0f * 105.0f)` using only multiplications: `(analogRead(0) * 0.000977517107f * 105.0f)`

HTH

Comment: Ok next question is: If I added a press button to the Digital input could I then use this to calibrate the potentiometers to zero? Whereby when I press the button all values start from zero no matter what possition the pots are in? I was going to do this in excel after however it seems possible to attempt it this afternoon. Would you use a switch statement or some sort of if statement?

Comment: @Alex I'm slightly confused because you are assigning values XPot,Ypot,Zpot via analogRead() continuously. If you have a push button, you could reset the values to 0, but on the next cylcle the values would be updated. Do you want to set custom XPot,YPot,ZPot values when the push button is pressed and analogRead values when the push button is released ? or use the push button as a toggle between preset values and analogRead values ? I'm afraid I don't fully understand what you are trying to achieve.